# proc glmselect and collinearity

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, sas

proc glmselect seems to be really powerful and offers 'feature selection' methods such as LASSO and LAR variable selection methods. I am just curious, can it also check for collinearity and ideally remove collinear variables? Or is this implicitly achieved via LASSO and LAR et al.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GLMSELECT procedure does not include collinearity diagnostics.  You can use the VIF and COLLIN options on the MODEL statement in PROC REG to get those diagnostics.

As you suspected, the variable selection process tends not to form models that include highly-correlated variables. Suppose that X1 and X2 are highly correlated and that X1 is already in the model. The X2 variable is not likely to be (immediately) chosen to be added to the model because it does not increase the predictive power of the model. Most of the explanatory power of X2 has already been included in the X1 variable.